# How to convert an input_shape to 3 dim "input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (35, 33297)"

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, lstm

Unable to find the exact input shape for my model, it is having (35,33297) shape

I have already tried it with np.expand dims but then also it is not working

````
model=Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(50,return_sequences=True, input_shape=(X_train.shape)))
model.add(LSTM(32, return_sequences=True ))
model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])```
```print("Train...")
model.fit(X_train,y_train,batch_size=5,epochs=10,verbose=1)```


```Train...
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-123-a64af5eee5e8> in <module>()
      1 print("Train...")
----> 2 model.fit(X_train,y_train,batch_size=5,epochs=10,verbose=1)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, **kwargs)
    950             sample_weight=sample_weight,
    951             class_weight=class_weight,
--> 952             batch_size=batch_size)
    953         # Prepare validation data.
    954         do_validation = False

ValueError: Error when checking input: expected lstm_37_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (35, 33297)```
````

Comment: You have given an array of size `(35, 33297)` to the LSTM. But the LSTM expects a `[batch_size, seq length, num  features]` array.  What is the error you got when you used `np.expand_dims`?

Comment: i did got any error while executing that

Comment: But if I am using batch size than it is showing that dim are greater than 3

Answer (score 0):

```
model.add(LSTM(50,return_sequences=True, input_shape=(timesteps, inputs)))
```

You have to define your LSTM like that. Input Shape has to be **(timesteps, inputs)**. timesteps is the size of one input sequence, and inputs how many variables you give the LSTM each timestep. And your training data has to be in the shape **(samples, timesteps, inputs)**.

Comment: I have created these model, input dims are 3 but then also it is showing error      
```model=Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(2,return_sequences=True, input_shape=(X_train.shape)))
model.add(LSTM(32, return_sequences=True ))
model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])```

Comment: ```ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer lstm_6: expected ndim=3, found ndim=4```

Comment: Can you print(X_train.shape). I am pretty sure you have 3 dim, instead of 2 when you define your first LSTM layer

Comment: yes, it is 3 dim I have expanded the dimension through using ```np.expand_dim``` method and then I print it then it is showing ``` (1,35,33297)```

Comment: and as i mentioned in my answer you have define it like this model.add(LSTM(50,return_sequences=True, input_shape=(X_train.shape[1], X_train.shape[2])))